# Flickering Pink background on all windows. Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Ever since upgrading my mid 2009 MacBook Pro from OS 10.6.8 to 10.10.1 Yosemite, the backgrounds to all my windows are vibrating flickering pink which is quite undesirable. At first I thought it was the acid flashbacks they promised me in high school but it's definitely only on my computer

Seriously, though, any idea as to why and any fixes?

I have reset my PRAM

Comment: Could be a video connection that just happened to come loose while you were updating OS. Loose cable can cause a vibrating pinkness. How do .jpgs look?

Comment: Thanks Wayfaring Strangeer but there was no video connection connected at time of upgrade. JOG's look bad where white is supposed to be they are pink.  ALL window backgrounds are flickering pink.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a GPU/driver mismatch, back buffer issue, or potential imminent failure.

Or it could be that GPU just isn't up to the task, running out of memory & refilling the buffers constantly.

Try System Prefs > Accessibility > Display & Reduce Transparency.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, I have already tried the reduce transparency to no avail. Sorry I didn't mention that. Otherwise I have very little understanding of your first sentence but it sounds bad.  If possible could you elaborate on those issues?

Comment: I might mention it even seems ghosting during the grey startup screen.

Comment: Since I have returtned to my dual monitor workstation and plugged in my 24" dell monitor, I see that the flickering remains on my laptop screen but is absent on the external Dell.  Any further thoughts?

Comment: assuming that's not a dual GPU machine, using one GPU for each screen, starts to feel like hardware fail on the screen itself, but it's not something I've ever seen, so it's a pure guess. I'm pretty much out of ideas as to a fix, sorry.

Comment: It does have dual graphics cards:  1. NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB,   2. NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT

Comment: then maybe try [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io) to see if you can figure out what's going on

Comment: thanks, tried but no joy although it's a nifty little app. Problem persists. Suppose I'll have to sacrifice my first born and enlist the "geniuses" at apple?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time but followed a suggestion elsewhere to clear the VRAM.  Turn off your laptop and when you turn it on then do so with  command+option+P+R pressed.  When you hear the startup tone then release...or it will reboot again.  ...I was still pink on my screen until I Quit my google drive that was loaded.  Rebooted and didnt lose the pink flickering until I quit the loaded google drive.  Has something to do with the google drive.  Hope this helps